# How to Parse This Type of JSON String Data

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

```
Object {percentage: Array(9), projects: Array(9), colors: Array(9)}
colors:Array(9)
  0:"#4d4d4d"
  1:"#5da5da"
  2:"#faa43a"
  3:"#60bd68"
  4:"#307d99"
  5:"#0275d8"
  6:"#cc4748"
  7:"#fdd400"
  8:"#f15854"
length:9
__proto__:Array(0)
percentage:Array(9)
  0:3
  1:6
  2:13
  3:12
  4:0
  5:47
  6:14
  7:4
  8:1
length:9
__proto__:Array(0)
projects:Array(9)
  0:"BHAWAN"
  1:"CORE"
  2:"DIST-NIC"
  3:"DIST-NKN"
  4:"FIREWALL"
  5:"NKN"
  6:"NMEICT"
  7:"PRAGATI"
  8:"WIFI"
length:9
__proto__:Array(0)
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: That's not JSON. It doesn't seem to be a string - is that text copied from the browser console, or? Where did it come from?

Comment: Please share more information regarding your problem because it is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it's not the JSON, but the `console` output for an object:

```
{
  percentage: [
    "#4d4d4d",
    "#5da5da",
    "#faa43a",
    "#60bd68",
    "#307d99",
    "#0275d8",
    "#cc4748",
    "#fdd400",
    "#f15854",
  ],
  projects: [
    3,
    6,
    13,
    12,
    0,
    47,
    14,
    4,
    1,
  ],
  colors: [
    "BHAWAN",
    "CORE",
    "DIST-NIC",
    "DIST-NKN",
    "FIREWALL",
    "NKN",
    "NMEICT",
    "PRAGATI",
    "WIFI",
  ]
}
```

And it seems for me that this is already a JSON object. So what's your issue?